# Input value toggles very quickly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a submit input as:-

```
<form method="POST">
    <input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" name="like" id="like" value="LIKE">
</form>
```

If the user presses it, I want to change it to `"LIKED"` and if it is pressed again, I want to change it back to `"LIKE"`. For this, I wrote this JS code:-

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x=document.getElementById("like");
      if(x.value=="LIKE") x.value="LIKED";
      else x.value="LIKE";
    }
</script>
```

Now the problem is that it does change, but that change lasts for a very small fraction of time. I can see it getting changed to `LIKED`, but it changes back to `LIKE` very quickly. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `form` element, as `action` did't defined , when action not defined for `form` element it means action path is relative or point to the current page so in your example the form submits to itself and after submitting the content will be refreshed, so the `clicked` title will be changed to `click`(the first state).
in the other hand `Form` is a HTML page when you `post` or `get` it, it's content get refreshed.

**Update:**

If you want to hold the state of button, it would be better to move out the button outside of `form` and then submit `form` manually something like:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
</form> 
<input onclick="myFunction()" name="like" id="like" value="LIKE" type="button" >

function myFunction() {
    var x=document.getElementById("like");
    if(x.value=="LIKE") x.value="LIKED";
    else x.value="LIKE";
     document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
```

Comment: I can't use the `GET` method because the url of my page is `http://localhost/checkPost.php?postId=9973&userId=2412`. Using `GET` will screw up everything if I'm not wrong. So can you suggest some other method I could use?

Comment: I didn't say you should use `get`, I meant your button title will be changed because it is in a `form` element, another way is moving out that submit button to outside the form and trigger it's click to submit the `form` element.

Comment: I'll look at it. Thanks!